# No water from the faucet

Tags: water-pressure

I have checked the circuit breaker and it is good. The sub pump is running alot because our basement flooded. The water pressure tank shows 70 psi and is covered in poop and water. We have no water coming from any faucet. Could the water pressure tank simply be clogged?[image][image][image]

Comment: I am not able to follow your question at all.  You posted 3 copies of the same photo that shows who-knows-what.  Is that your sump pump?  (BTW, I'm not sure what a "sub pump" is in this context.)  How is what you're showing related to your presumably water pump and pressure tank system which I assume means you are on a well.  Please edit your question to clearly state the problem and add some description of your system and some relevant photos.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the gauge if the gauge is broken and reading 70 psi your actual pressure may be zero,

whatever is going on your drinking water should be a sealed system from your sump pump and if you have a shallow well jet pump in the basement when it flooded that may have taken the well pump out.